# UILabel sometimes renders NSAttributedString with a 1px tall line above text

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, core-text

This is a bit of an odd issue for me. I'm displaying some complex attributed text in a label and it was working well until recently a small grey line began to appear above certain lines of text like below:

[image]

Note that this is distinct from the tableview cell separator and only appears above the rect of the label.

With a bit of debugging, I also noticed the line doesn't appear when I don't have the little blue bracketed "flair" tag:
[image]

I am using the following code to add the problematic blue tags:

```
let captionFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.caption1);
let offset = (bodyFont.lineHeight / 2) - (captionFont.lineHeight / 2)

attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : captionFont, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : Constants.linkColor, NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset:offset], range: flairRange!)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this a CoreText bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, I determined the issue only appeared when `offset` was a decimal value. When I simply replaced my offset line with

`let offset = ceil((bodyFont.lineHeight / 2) - (captionFont.lineHeight / 2))`

the line no longer appeared. I suspect this is a CoreText bug.

[image]